# How is a surjection $f : (0,1) \to [0,1]$ possible?

Tags: functions

I found an example of a **surjective** function $f : (0,1) \to [0,1]$, namely,

$$x \mapsto \left| \, \sin \left(\frac1x \right) \, \right|$$

However, when I thought about this again it sounds completely wrong. **Why?**

For each number $y \in [0,1]$ there should be a match $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x)=y$ but now we are left with $2$ numbers, $0$ and $1$, that don't have a match because we *used all numbers* in $(0,1)$.

Comment: This is how infinities work. Think about a surjective function from the even integers to the integers, to get some intuition.

Comment: I don't think "*why*" is a particularly good question to ask in mathematics. It implies some sort of causal link between mathematical statements which doesn't really exist. A mathematical statement really only has one objective property: its truth value. That is, a statement is either true or false, and that's about all you can objectively say about it. Everything else, like its importance, meaning, cause, consequence and so on are, to one extent, subjective.

Comment: A harder case would be a surjective function $[0,1] \mapsto (0,1)$

Comment: "but now we are left with 2 numbers, 0 and 1, that don't have a match because we used all numbers in (0,1)" That'd be an issue with an *injective* function.  And it's not a really an issue as the sets are infinite.

Comment: Note your function isn't injective as $\sin \frac 1{\frac 1{2\pi}} = \sin \frac 1{\frac 1{4\pi}}$ and indeed for any $x$ $\sin \frac 1{\frac 1{\frac 1x + 2\pi}} = \sin (\frac 1x + 2\pi) = \sin \frac 1x$.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 3):

$\left\lvert\sin\frac1{2/\pi}\right\rvert=1$ and $\left\lvert\sin\frac1{1/\pi}\right\rvert=0$. I don't quite see why you'd stress over $0$ and $1$, when in fact for all $y\in [0,1]$ the set $\{x\in(0,1)\,:\, \left\lvert\sin\frac1x\right\rvert=y\}$ is infinite.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking then... you are saying that $0$ and $1$ dont have a match, this answer is showing you are wrong. @ArielCohen

Comment: @Ariel Cohen. This is perfect answer, because shows, that your sentence "we used all numbers in $(0,1)$" is wrong - brought numbers are used for borders of $[0,1]$.

Comment: it is infinite but we are talking about same kind of infinite between them

Comment: "that doesn't answer my question" then what *was* your question? You gave a true statement, you said it felt wrong even though you knew it was true, you explained why it felt it should be wrong, Gae S. explained what was wrong with your reasoning.  In what way is that *not* an answer to your question?  What were you asking if you *weren't* asking what was wrong with way it felt wrong. (Note: you never actually *did* ask a question.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds wrong but it is not. It is a well known fact that $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ have the same cardinality i.e there is a bijective function between them

Comment: I already know that there is a bijective function between them, that is not what I asked

Comment: Can you find a surjective function between $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}\cup \{+,*\}$ ?

Comment: @ArielCohen: Perhaps, but from the phrase "we used all the numbers in $(0, 1)$" it did seem as though you felt that there wasn't.

Comment: "I already know that there is a bijective function between them, that is not what I asked"  Then what on earth *did* you ask?  If you already know bijective functions exist then you know surjective functions exist.